# Combine strings in numerical order line by line loop (vb.net)

Tags: string, vb.net, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a complex type of string that I simply need re-arranging the first **" ":** section of each line based on the line number.

Example: RichTextBox1:

```
{"5":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"},
 "3":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"},
 "10":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"},
 "4":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"},
 "2":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"}}
```

I want to find and replace numbers based on the current line number. As you can see there are 5 lines. So the string should show **"1":** then the start of the second line **"2":** and so on...

**The output I would like to make would look like:**

```
{"1":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"},
 "2":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"},
 "3":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"},
 "4":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"},
 "5":{"var1" : "Data", "var2" : "Data", "var3": "Data"}}
```

The way I currently know how to find and replace text is like this on VB.NET:

```
Dim Lines() As String = RichTextbox1.Lines
        Lines(1) = Lines(1).Replace("""1""", """1""")
        Lines(2) = Lines(2).Replace("""1""", """2""")
        Lines(3) = Lines(3).Replace("""1""", """3""")
        Lines(4) = Lines(4).Replace("""1""", """4""")
        Lines(5) = Lines(5).Replace("""1""", """5""")
RichTextBox1.Lines = Lines
```

But there are two problems here.

**Problem 1:** I need to pre-specify how many lines. In my application, I would not know how many lines the data will contain. And this will be different day to day, therefore a loop is required?

**Problem 2:** I need to pre-specify which number within the line to replace but that is an unknown variable. It could be any number in that string.

Any ideas on how to make this type of function? In short, it simply needs to loop through line by line and assign a number at the start of each line within the " ": section such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Ok, so pretty much, you want to discard the numbering that exists, and add your own.

Comment: Since that is json (its not really a string, simple or complex), deserialize it; renumber the element, then re-serialize it.  You run the risk of invalidating it by tinkering with it directly.

Comment: I've been editing JSON as string for a long time on a number of scripts without any issues but for the type of task in hand I do not know the right loop in vb.net to do this. Do you have any examples of your suggestion? I know how to find and replace by line number but it needs to loop through each line by line, assign a number then re-construct the original content. I'm stuck at that part. Any ideas?